# A process with stationary independent increments cannot have fixed time of discontinuity

Tags: continuity, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

For any cadlag process $\{X_t\}$ define, as it is customary, $\Delta X_t=X_t-X_{t-}$ the process of jumps of $X$.

We say that $t$ is a fixed time of discontinuity if
$$
\mathsf{P}\{\Delta X_t\neq 0\}>0
$$

Following [Jacod and Shiryaev's](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05265-5) book we have that if $\{T_n\}$ is a sequence of stopping time that exhausts the jumps of $X$ the set
$$
D_n =\{t\geq 0| \mathsf{P}\{T_n=t\}>0\}
$$
is at most countable.

Even though this claim is quite intuitive, I miss a formal argument to convince myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process is PIIS iff it has a deterministic, time-homogeneous characteristic exponent $\psi_X$ (see II.4.19. in Jacod and Shiryaev for details). By definition $\Delta X_t:=X_t-\lim_{t_n\uparrow t}X_{t_n}=X_t-X_{t^-}$. By dominated convergence and continuous mapping:
$$E[e^{i\xi \Delta X_t}]=\lim_{t_n\uparrow t}E[e^{i\xi(X_t-X_{t_n})}]=\lim_{t_n\uparrow t}E[e^{i\xi X_{t-t_n}}]=\lim_{t_n\uparrow t}e^{(t-t_n)\psi_X(\xi)}=1,\,\forall \xi$$
Since $1=\int_\mathbb{R}e^{i\xi x}\delta_0(dx)$ we get $P(\Delta X_t=0)=1,\,\forall t$.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't get how you conclude $\mathsf{P}\{\Delta X_t=0\}=1$.

Comment: The distribution of $\Delta X_t$ is a delta measure at $0$, because characteristic functions completely characterize probability measures. @AlmostSureUser